# gcp dataproc how to use the same python between interactive login and ssh commands

Tags: python, bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

for a gcp dataproc cluster, if I ssh to run a command

```
gcloud compute ssh --internal-ip mycluster-m some_command.sh
```

the python I get is

```
/usr/bin/python
```

However when I login, I get a system conda python --

```
/opt/conda/default/bin/python
```

sourcing .bashrc in my script doesn't help, and I see the .bashrc has

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

which I think means it wont do anything - however I don't see how python gets set to the conda environment in what follows in the bashrc (this is dataproc image version 1.4)

The other confusing thing is how to install packages in the initialization script. I primarily do adhoc interactive work on the dataproc, and I've learned to do things like

```
sudo /opt/conda/default/bin/python3 -m pip install tensorflow<1.15 google-cloud-storage
```

to get my packages available. But now when I run a ssh command, I'm given a different python?

What do I source to get the conda python running when I ssh commands?

Comment: Compare which user you are logging in as after logging in: `whoami`

Answer (score 1):

SSH-with-command just runs the command by forking instead of creating a new login shell which is why python env is not activated. This is one of several cases where you do not get the user python.

For your use case, sourcing `/etc/profile.d/effective-python.sh` is a reasonable approach.